# I don't have a disposal, my kitchen sink fills when my dishwasher empties, why?

Tags: plumbing

I don't have a disposal, when the dishwasher empties my kitchen sink fills

Comment: Can you post a photo of the plumbing under the sink?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the pipes below the kitchen / washer are starting to plug up. It would be a good time to run a snake down the line or have a plumber do it. It will get worse once this has started, if you have trees and a older house roots may be making there way into the drain lines and a cutter tip on a drain auger may be required. I mention this because I have owned several older houses that had this problem, one I only had to clean out in the spring the other I had to replace the old concrete drain pipe.

Comment: Good answer, though my initial (less invasive/complicated) approach would be to dump some drain cleaner down the sink.